# Understanding Mathlib/MeasureTheory Notation

Tags: lean, lean4, lean-mathlib

I want to understand `Mathlib/MeasureTheory`, and in particular I want to understand `Mathlib/MeasureTheory/Integral`. I'm having difficulty with the notation. I struggle to find the correct file to "start" with when reading a new part of Mathlib, so I typically tend to find something that seems sufficiently basic which I want to learn about and start tracing dependencies. (If anyone has a better way, please help me...) I'm struggling to understand some of the notation I'm finding. For example, go to `MeasureTheory/Integral/SetToL1.lean`. We find the code

```
/-- Extend `Set α → E →L[ℝ] F` to `(α →₁ₛ[μ] E) →L[] F`. -/
def setToL1SCLM' {T : Set α → E →L[ℝ] F} {C : ℝ} (hT : DominatedFinMeasAdditive μ T C)
    (h_smul : ∀ c : , ∀ s x, T s (c • x) = c • T s x) : (α →₁ₛ[μ] E) →L[] F :=
  LinearMap.mkContinuous
    ⟨⟨setToL1S T, setToL1S_add T (fun _ => hT.eq_zero_of_measure_zero) hT.1⟩,
      setToL1S_smul T (fun _ => hT.eq_zero_of_measure_zero) hT.1 h_smul⟩
    C fun f => norm_setToL1S_le T hT.2 f
```

Take `E →L[ℝ] F`, for instance, though I could have chosen quite a few examples. When I hover over it, it calls itself a continuous map between modules, but doesn't give a location in Mathlib to find this explanation. Needless to say

```
/-- Extend `Set α → E →L[ℝ] F` to `(α →₁ₛ[μ] E) →L[] F`. -/
```

means nothing to me right now. Hence: Is there a "nice" path through which to explore `Mathlib/MeasureTheory`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with reading the [relevant chapter](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathematics_in_lean/C10_Integration_and_Measure_Theory.html) of [Mathematics in Lean](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathematics_in_lean). You can also right click and choose "Go to definition" when you see an unknown notation or definition.

Comment: Didn't know that existed. Thank you.